# C# and MonoDevelop on Ubuntu - missing system libraries contents

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I wanted to make a use of Mono on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS in order to write some client-server app using C# language.
I followed [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) tutorial and installed everything Mono needs to be compiling and running C# .NET apps on Ubuntu.
Then I installed MonoDevelop 5.9.6 according to [this](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/) tutorial which was actually installing three packages: monodevelop, l monodevelop-nunit, monodevelop-versioncontrol  (I skipped database package as I don't need it for now).

I created simple console application in MonoDevelop and now I am trying to use some code which referencen to System.Net.Sockets (and other) system library class. I added to my project's references the System.Net.dll, which is located under *usr/lib/mono/4.5* after Mono installation.
Apparently I cannot compile my app as I get the errors like:

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Sockets' does not exist in the namespace `System.Net'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (Communicator.Presentation)
```

I completely cannot get what is going on here. I've searched through net and forums and cannot find the answer for that issue.

I am also providing the screenshot from my PC with MonoDevelop opened where you can see that System.Net reference is added to the project, but the inside classes are not visible. When I type "System.Net." it only allows me to choose "System.Net.IPEndPointCollection" and nothing else:
[image: screenshot from MonoDevelop]

EDIT:
What is also weird it that if i double-click on that System.net reference in MonoDevelop in the "Assembly Browser" windows I can see the contents of this "System.net.dll" and especially System.Net.Sockets is present there...:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** need **System.Net.dll** to be included, as you are looking for **System.Net.Sockets namespace** which exists inside **System.dll**. So you need to add reference to System.dll. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.

So you need following reference:

> using System;

I am also attaching my Ubuntu with MonoDevelop snapshots. In these snapshots, you can see that I don't have any reference to System.Net.dll, inside my project references, just System.dll is needed.

[image: System.Net.Sockets reference]

[image: System.dll reference]

Hope this helps.